# Unable to set interface up in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager, ifconfig

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new laptop. During the installation I was able to connect to a network, so when I finished the installation and updated the software, Ubuntu is not showing any visible network.

when I run `sudo lshw -C network` I got the next output:

```
*-network DISABLED
    description: Wireless interface
    product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    vendor Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    logical name: wlp1s0
    version: 00
    serial: 80:30:49:04:30:d3
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33 MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
    resources: irq:66 ioport:20000(size=256) memory:d05000000-d050ffff
```

Also checked ip interfaces with `ip link`, and tried to set them up with ip link:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noquere state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:30:49:04:30:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

but then this error appeared when I tried `sudo ip link set wlp1s0 up`:
`RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`

Don't know where to go from here, also tried to restart network manager but it didn't solve the problem,

Actually the thing that is breaking up the network is the software update, but obviously I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solve it upgrading the Linux kernel to a newer version, also upgrading ubuntu to 20.04 fixed all this problems and other incompatibilities that I had.